# /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign with xcode 9 automatic code signing

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins-pipeline, code-signing

Automatic signing configured with Xcode9 working fine with machine but giving below error when I access that machine remotely via ssh & run through commandline bash scripts which is using Xcodebuild with Automatic code sign style or if same code base is configured with jenkins pipeline & triggered a run still give below error message:-

```
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign A7F8FCD694D7923A3E57826398C3380E2E5A5446 --entitlements  unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

not able to understand what is wrong while automatic signing is working with one machine so it should work when somebody try to run remotely as well.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. with Xcode too